# What is the symbol of the `mux` chip in C?

Tags: c, symbols, boolean-logic, mux

I was studying logic gates when I came to know that each logic gate was already defined in `C`. For example, for the `AND` logic gate, the symbol is `&`. For `OR`, it is `|`. But I could not find a symbol for the `MUX` chip.

So, if there is a symbol for `MUX`, could someone tell me? If there isn't, could someone tell me how to replicate a `MUX` chip in C?

Comment: How exactly would you expect a MUX operator to work?  How would you supply its inputs?

Comment: @Dmitri, I would make a function in which I will pass it's inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be advised that C operates at a much higher level of abstraction than logical gates, so making such comparisons might lead to confusions. That said, the closest you might come to a *demultiplexer* (I'll start with that since it's simpler) is the *left shift operator*:

```
a << b
```

This expression, assuming that `a` and `b` are `int` expressions, will produce a new `int` whose bits are the bits of `a` shifted to the left `b` times. For example, if `a` is `0100011011010110` and `b` is 3, the result will be `0011011010110000`. Now, if `a` is either 0 or 1 and you interpret the resulting integer as being a bus, this corresponds to a demultiplexer.

A *multiplexer*/*selector* can be implemented by the *right shift operator* `>>`, which shifts bits to the right. However, the result must be `&`'ed with 1 in order to clear any other bits than the one you were interested in:

```
(c >> b) & 1
```

This effectively selects the bit at index `b` (starting at the least significant bit) from `c`.

Comment: So you mean to say, that you cannot make a `MUX` in `C`? (By the way I didn't downvote or upvote anyone's answer till now.).

Comment: Looks like we all got one except for one answer that immediately got upvoted. I'll go ahead and cancel out the downvote you got.

Comment: do you even know what a mux is?

Comment: @AshishAhuja: What I'm saying is that the question doesn't make sense because a MUX is a _digital circuit_, not a programming construct. However, if you interpret `int` values as buses, you can make something that has similar effect - but when your program is executed, the operation will most likely not be executed by an actual MUX (except in the sense that MUXes are a part of the Arithmetic-Logic Unit of your processor, but this is, as mentioned, on a much lower level).

Comment: @Adam: Thanks; same to you.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset, yeah I wanted to make a virtual `MUX` which will not be executed by an actual `MUX`. Just virtual.

Comment: @AshishAhuja: Then, I believe that my suggested expressions will do what you want (as long as your bus doesn't have more bits than an `int`, typically 32).

Comment: @Jasen, yes I know what a `MUX` is. It is a chip which selects one of several analog signals (or maybe digital), and forwards the input into a single line.

Comment: ...I, on the other hand, mixed up the definitions of multiplexer and demultiplexer; a correction is coming shortly.

Comment: mux is like CD4519, analogue switches are different.

Comment: One more downvote - can the downvoters please explain why?

Answer (score 6):

Closest is the conditional operator:  `?` `:`

eg:

```
 x ? b : a
```

if  `x` is `0` you get `a` if it's `1` (or anything else) you get `b`

This operator works on entire values, like `||` `&&` `==` and `!` do. It does not operate on bits as `^` `~` `&` and `|` do.

There is no direct equivalent for a multi-input mux.
but you can fake one using an anonymous array, eg:

```
 ((int[]){a,b,c,d,})[x]
```

but many people frown on constructions of that form.

if you need a bitwise mux you'll need to build it from the bitwise operators
 eg:

```
 a ^ (( b ^ a ) & x)
```

Answer (score 1):

C has four bitwise operators:

- AND, `&`, as in `a & b`
- OR, `|`, as in `a | b`
- XOR, `^`, as in `a ^ b`
- NOT, `~`, as in `~a`

There is no `MUX` operator.

Be careful about your phrasing. These are called *bitwise* operators, and are analogous to logic gates applied to all bits in an integral type. In C *logical* operators are different.

Comment: So is there a way to make a `MUX` chip using these?

Comment: @AshishAhuja a MUX isn't something you'd normally code at the C level. The same task is usually accomplished in several other ways, such as a conditional (`if`, `switch` or `?:`), and array lookup, bit packing, or others. It all depends on what you want to use your MUX for. Remember that C is not a hardware language, it's a high level language.

Comment: thanks for informing me that, but if you want to do it, what is wrong. I am doing this as I was learning circuits and hardware. And, I didn't want to do soldering, as the last I did soldering on a circuit, I burned one of my finger.

Comment: soldering without burning fingers is an important skill. not a skill I have fully mastered, I count it a success if I have no blisters the next day.

Answer (score 1):

The `|`, `&`, and `~` operators are bitwise operators.  They work in parallel on individual bits in the operands.  There is no corresponding bitwise operator for a multiplexer.  The ternary operator:

```
output = cond ? a : b
```

comes close, but the selector operand is treated as a single bit, and not a vector of bits (that is, all output bits come from `a` or all output bits come from `b`, you can't have some of the output bits come from `a` and some come from `b`).  To get a true bitwise multiplexer, where the selector is a vector that selects individual bits from `a` or `b`, you can implement it the way you would build one from discrete logic gates:

```
output = (cond & a) | (~cond & b);
```

Here, a `1` in a `cond` bit allows the corresponding bit from `a` to pass, and blocks the corresponding bit from `b` (because `b` is masked with the inverse condition).  A `0` in a `cond` bit blocks the corresponding bit from `a`, and allows the corresponding bit from `b` to pass.  The two masked values are bitwise OR'd together, so a bit of output is either the corresponding bit from `a` of `b`, depending upon the state of the corresponding bit in `c`.